# Blackberry text and button focus issue

Tags: blackberry, button, focus, label

Hi so i have a screen which contains a labelfield with a lot of text in, then at the bottom of the screen there is a button.

As the button has focus when the screen is shown, only the bottom section of the label is visible and its not possible to scroll as only the button can gain focus.

How does i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `LabelField` to `RichTextField`. Another option would be to add `NullField` before adding `LabelField`.

Answer (score 1):

By adding an empty field on the top of the screen with a lesser layout and override the drawFocus() method and leave it blank, Thus, the empty field would be focussed first and since it is over ridden it doesnot show any effect. And one could see the text, which is written on the beginning of the screen.

Hope it solves your problem.
Happy Coding
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of label field, add rich text field and give focus for it like this
RichTextField rt  = new RichTextField("text",  RichTextField.FOCUSABLE );